# Some other secure way to pass data to server other than hidden fields

Tags: php, jquery, html, logic

While editing some form fields we pass the id or some unique id to identify the fields while updating in database.
Is there any secure way to do this, as hidden fields can be tampered with or changed?

Comment: Keep it on the server, in the session for example.

Comment: Any data saved on client side can be changed. Use session instead

Comment: Use SESSION to pass data.

Comment: hey could u please give an example. as how will I be able to identify the data uniquely.

Comment: either give an id that makes no sense to user and use it as a key to find the var in your session, or even better, directly from php, know what you need from session according to the page you are on for instance.

Actually u should provide an example of what you try to perform :)

Comment: Thanks antoni that is much better way to identify unique id.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to hide this id? what's your actual concern here? intentionally changing data of which user doesn't have privilege?

You can normally send id using get or post parameter. in your update page just ensure if current user has the privilege to update.